# Is there a better way to delete all the .py and .pyc files in a given subdirectory?

Tags: python, django, loops, django-migrations, coding-efficiency

I wrote a script to delete all the .py and .pyc files in a given sub-directory called "migrations". The end goal is to remove all migration files from my django project, so there are multiple sub-folders called "migrations" and I would like to remove all .py and .pyc (except **init**.py) from these folders. The script I wrote below works but I am new to python and figure there has to be a better way then all the nested loops. Any suggestions? This is a windows system which complicates things for me.

```
import os
import sys

def delete_py(path, subfolder):
    try:
        if os.path.exists(path):
            for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk(path):
                for dir in dirs:
                    if dir == subfolder:
                        goto = os.path.join(root, dir)
                        for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk(goto):
                            for file in files:
                                if (file.lower().endswith('.py') | 
                                    file.lower().endswith('.pyc')) and 
                                    file != '__init__.py':
                                    print('file: ', file)
                                    # will change to os.remove once finsihed
    except:
        print('Unable to delete files')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    current = os.getcwd()
    delete_py(current, 'migrations')
```

Comment: Why not just give the `migrations` path to `os.walk()`? You are needlessly everything else too.

Comment: Note that you don't want to use `|`! That's bitwise or, not the boolean logic OR. And `str.endswith()` takes a tuple of options to test, so `file.lower().endswith(('*.py', '*.pyc'))` suffices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing double work with calling `os.walk()` for subdirectories that will already be handled by the outer `os.walk()` loop.

All you need to test for is if `migrations` is an element in the current `root` path to the directory being handled:

```
def delete_py(path, subfolder):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        if subfolder in root.split(os.sep):
            # has subfolder as a directory name in the path, delete .py files here
            for file in files:
                if file == '__init__.py':
                    continue
                if file.endswith(('.py', '.pyc')):
                    os.unlink(os.path.join(root, file))
```

You could also just use a recursive glob pattern, with the [`glob` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html):

```
from itertools import chain

def delete_py(path, subfolder):
    pyfiles = glob.iglob(f'**/{subfolder}/**/*.py', recursive=True)
    pycfiles = glob.iglob(f'**/{subfolder}/**/*.pyc', recursive=True)
    for filename in chain(pyfiles, pycfiles):
        if os.path.basename(filename) == '__init__.py':
            continue
        os.unlink(filename)
```

Comment: Thank you, that's much better. Just had to change "root.split(os.pathsep):"  to "root.split(os.path.sep):"

Comment: @dpoiesz: apologies for that, that was actually meant to be `os.sep`.

Answer (score 1):

One `os.walk` should do most of the work for you; the only other loop you should need is to go trhough the `files` in each directory it gets you to.  You certainly don't need a *nested* `os.walk`.

Answer (score 0):

simply use

- for linux
  "find . -name "*.pyc"  -delete"
- for windows:
  "DEL /S /Q *.pyc"